# Integral of a CDF

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, integral, partial-moments

I'm solving a problem where I've this 'expectation':
$$ \int_{0}^y x\cdot f(x) dx $$
where $f(x)$ is a *PDF* with support on $[0, z]$, with $z>y$. Is there a way to rewrite it without the integral and as a function of the *CDF*? I've tried integration by parts, but without great success:
$$ \int_{0}^y x\cdot f(x) dx = y\cdot F(y) -\int_0^y F(x) dx $$
I have hard time to solve the second part.

Comment: There's no further simplification possible. Are you sure those are all the details given in the problem?

Comment: Your expression is a partial moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For cdfs $F$ of distributions with supports on $(0,a)$, $a$ being possibly $+\infty$, a  useful representation of the expectation is
$$\mathbb{E}_F[X]=\int_0^a x \text{d}F(x)=\int_0^a \{1-F(x)\}\text{d}x$$
by applying integration by parts,
\begin{align*}\int_0^a x \text{d}F(x)&=-\int_0^a x \text{d}(1-F)(x)\\&=-\left[x(1-F(x))\right]_0^a+\int_0^a \{1-F(x)\}\text{d}x\\&=-\underbrace{a(1-F(a))}_{=0}+\underbrace{0(1-F(0))}_{=0}+\int_0^a \{1-F(x)\}\text{d}x\end{align*}
In the special case when $a=+\infty$,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-F(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-F(x)}{1/x}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-f(x)}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2f(x)=0$$
by [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and the fact that $xf(x)$ is integrable at infinity (the expectation $\mathbb E_F[X]$ is assumed to exist).

In the current case, one can turn the integral into an expectation as
$$\int_0^y x\text{d}F(x)=F(y)\int_0^y x\frac{\text{d}F(x)}{F(y)}=\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{F}}[X]$$with $$\tilde{F}(x)=F(x)\big/F(y)\mathbb{I}_{(0,y)}(x)$$Thus
$$\int_0^y x\text{d}F(x)=F(y)\int_0^y \{1-F(x)\big/F(y)\}\text{d}x$$
which is the representation that you found.

Comment: Why can you write $\begin{align*}\int_0^a x \text{d}F(x)&=-\int_0^a x \text{d}(1-F)(x)$? is it because the derivative of $(1-x) = -dx$ so the derivative of $-(1-x) = dx$?

Comment: Thank you, and sorry about the improper format equation.

Comment: How can you guarantee that $-a(1-F(a)) = 0$ in case $a=+\infty$, as allowed at the top? It would seem that $\lim_{a\rightarrow +\infty} -a(1-F(a))$ is indeterminate with $(1-F(a)) \rightarrow 0$ but $a \rightarrow +\infty$. But I guess there is a way to show the product still converges to $0$? How does that work?

Comment: @Xi'an: I am still not sure I understand why $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^2 f(x) = 0$. I am guessing it has to do with the comment you make below that "() is integrable at infinity (the expectation [] is assumed to exist)." If you're able to further explain this --- even if it's only in the comments --- that would be very helpful. Otherwise, thank you already for the addition!

Comment: If $\lim_{+\infty} x^2f(x)>0$, there exists $x_0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $x^2f(x)>\epsilon$ when $x>x_0$, hence $xf(x)>\epsilon/x$ when $x>x_0$ and$$\int_{x_0}^\infty\epsilon/x\,\text dx=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to take it, unfortunately.

By the way, this integral shows up in [expected shortfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall) (conditional value-at-risk) measure in risk management. It's used so much, that if there was a shortcut through CDF, people would have figured it out long ago.